# Format (remove class/parens) Spark CSV saveAsTextFile output?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to strip wrapping class or array text from CSV data saved via saveAsTextFile without having to a non-Spark post-processing step.

I have some TSV data in big files, which I feed to an RDD.

```
 val testRdd = sc.textFile(_input).filter(!_.startsWith("unique_transaction_id")).map(x => x.toLowerCase).map(x => x.split('\t')).map(x => Test(x(0),x(1)))

testRdd.saveAsTextFile("test")
```

This saves the data wrapped by the class name:

```
head -n 1 part-00000
Test("1969720fb3100608b38297aad8b3be93","active")
```

I've also tried consuming it into an unnamed class (?) instead of a case class.

```
val testRdd = sc.textFile(_input).filter(!_.startsWith("unique_transaction_id")).map(x => x.toLowerCase).map(x => x.split('\t')).map(x => (x(0),x(1)))
```

testRdd.saveAsTextFile("test2")

This yields

```
("1969720fb3100608b38297aad8b3be93","active")
```

which still needs post-processing in order to remove the wrapping parens.

In order to strip the wrapping chars, I tried flatMap(), but the RDD is apparently not the correct type:

```
testRdd.flatMap(identity).saveAsTextFile("test3")
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ((String, String)) => (String, String)
 required: ((String, String)) => TraversableOnce[?]
              testRdd.flatMap(identity).saveAsTextFile("test3")
```

So...do I need to convert the RDD to some other type of RDD, or is there another way to save the RDD as CSV such that the wrapping text is stripped?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
val testRdd = sc.textFile(_input).filter(!_.startsWith("unique_transaction_id"))
                                 .map(x => x.toLowerCase.split('\t'))
                                 .map(x => x(0)+","+x(1))
```

What we've done hear is after filter your header, you can lowercase your string in the same map passage saving also some unnecessary extra mapping.

This will create an RDD[String] that you can save as a CSV format.

**PS:**

- The extension of the output of the saved rdd is not a csv but the format is!
- This is not the optimal and only solution, but it will do the job for you!

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for not only answering the question, but pointing out the simplification of doing multiple steps in a single map() call.

Answer (score 2):

```
val testRdd = sc.textFile(_input).filter(!_.startsWith("unique_transaction_id")).map(x => x.toLowerCase).map(x => x.split('\t')).map(x => x(0)+","+x(1))
```

This would write the output as csv

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [Spark CSV Library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

Answer (score 0):

val logFile = "/input.csv"

val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(master="local", appName="Mi app", conf)

val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()

val lower = logData.map(line => line.toLowerCase)